# Navigation Best Practices - Complex Navigation

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

:)

I am trying to work correctly with navigation.
I am writing a nativescript app.
The advance navigation issue is a little bit new to me.

I am trying to create this navigation scenario:

**page1 -> page2**

**page2 -> page3**

**page3 -> page4**

**page4 -> page2**

And I want the history to be **page1/page2**...

What is the right way to do that? this is related to children? Should I modify the history or should I go back twice from page4 to page2?

I would be very happy to get an advance tutorials in that issue... :)

Thank you so much!